# Hypothetical terrorism

Tags: united-states, nevada

Let's say I land a drone on someone's roof. They spend $1000 removing it and I buy the drone for $40. I know that technically I could be charged with multiple things, I am asking:

1. Is it *likely* law enforcement will perform a full trace of where the drone came from and identify me, or can the person (who I know) identify me? Even if they do, is that evidence of anything?
2. Is this an effective Terrorist strategy?
3. Assuming any of the above, is this actually worthwhile for law enforcement to pursue?

Comment: #1 and #3 don't really seem to be questions about the law itself, but about discretionary police investigative techniques, which are outside the scope of this site.  #2 doesn't seem to have anything to do with law at all, and I don't even really understand what you mean by it.

Comment: Landing a drone on someone's roof isn't terrorism under any legal definition I'm aware of, so this entire question is pointless, even if it were on-topic, which as Nate Eldredge has explained, is not true.

Comment: @Nij True, but it is trespass and nuisance. If the question came at it from that direction it would be ok.

Comment: It would still be off-topic. 1. is a question of police efficiency and political motivation, 2. is a question about realpolitik, and 3. is the same as 1. @DaleM

Comment: @Nij  I think you are focusing too much on the fact that the OP doesn’t really know what they want to ask. Try looking at the issues more broadly and there are legal matters involved. It does need a rewrite though.

Comment: I think they know exactly what they want to ask. If they were interested in whether the proposed action is terrorism (viz. is harassment, trespass, nuisance) they'd have asked that. They just haven't asked it in the appropriate place.

Comment: Why? Are you thinking of doing this? Because (I would not call this "terrorism" just simple trespassing and annoying, but to use your words here...) I would advise not committing terrorism.

Answer (score -3):

Here are my TENTATIVE thoughts

1. No, drone pilot arrests are rare for any reason
2. Yes
3. Based on lack of past cases, no

Comment: No, landing a drone on a roof is not terrorism nor would it be an effective form of terrorism.